# Am receiving the error Am receiving the error Exception in thread "main" java... full error below

Tags: java

Am receiving the error in the title, don't know what it means/ how to fix it

The program is supposed to have an array of 100 random numbers from 1-100, and to make an array of all the numbers in that array that are divisble by 4, and to list them

```
public class JavaProgram{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        int [] hundredNumbers = new int [100];

        for ( int i=0; i <hundredNumbers.length; i++ )
            hundredNumbers[i] = (int) Math.random() * 100;

        int [] multiplesOfFour = new int [100];

        for ( int i=0; i<hundredNumbers.length; i++)
            multiplesOfFour[i] = hundredNumbers[i];

        getEvenMultiples(multiplesOfFour);

        for ( int i=0; i < multiplesOfFour.length; i++ )
            System.out.print (multiplesOfFour[i] + " ");
    }

    public static int[] getEvenMultiples(int[] x){

        int result [] = {};
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length ; i++){

            if ( x[i] % 4 == 0 ){
                result = new int [++count];
                result [count] = x[i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

I should get a list of all the numbers that are divisble by 4, but get

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
>           at JavaProgram.getEvenMultiples(JavaProgram.java:27)
>           at JavaProgram.main(JavaProgram.java:13)"

Comment: `getEvenMultiples` returns an array but you are not handling the result from calling it so even if you fixed the bugs in that method your code prints the wrong array

Comment: You should always use braces with `for`, `while`, `if` and `switch` constructs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that result array in the getEvenMultiples function.

You use count (the length of the array) as the index, and because the length is always bigger then the biggest index you get this error. For example you have an array with length two you can only use the indexes 0 and 1. So you would actually do something like "result [count - 1] = x[i];"

The other problem you have is that you always delete the hole array when you do "result = new int [++count];". You actually want to use a list like `ArrayList` ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html ). Here you find information about how to use an `ArrayList`: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-arraylist .

Ah and u never use the result from the getEvenMultiples function in your main function.

Comment: I added the getEvenMultiples function into the code and the "result [count - 1] = x[i];". And how to i not delete the whole array every single time.

Comment: Is that a question?

Comment: Yes, what should I do so that I don't "always delete the whole array when you do "result = new int [++count];"", because I haven't learned the ArrayList thing

Comment: I addet a link to a patge that explains how to use ArrayLists.
Another option would be to make the result array as big as the input array in the begin of the function and than just use the numbers that are not 0 when you output the result. (And of cause only create the array ones at the start of the getEvenMultiples function)